# Move image left or right on swipe

Tags: android

I am developing an android application in which the requirement is to place three pictures, one on each other. When i swipe to left, image should move left side and if i swipe to the right the image should move right side, like `parallex view`. Below is my `xml` page:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.layerapp.layerapp.MainActivity">

<ImageView
android:id="@+id/forest"
android:layout_width="1000dp"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:src="@drawable/forest"
android:scaleType="fitXY"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Need help on java logic. Could anyone give me idea please.

Comment: post your code here

Comment: My xml file code is

Comment: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    tools:context="com.example.layerapp.layerapp.MainActivity">

   `

Comment: ` <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/forest"
        android:layout_width="1000dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

`

Comment: `        android:src="@drawable/forest"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"

        />

</LinearLayout>`

Comment: i just created xml file please help me in java logic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did the same thing using swipe card library go through it

https://github.com/Diolor/Swipecards